# Number of zeros of quadratic equation over finite fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ denote the finite field with $q$ elements and Ch$\mathbb{F}_q\neq 2$. What is the number of solutions of the quadratic equation
$X_1^2+\cdots + X_r^2=0$ in $\mathbb{F}_q^m$ for $1\leq r\leq m$.

Comment: If $r$ is odd, at least $3$, then the number of solutions equals $q^{m-1}$.  If $r$ is even, say $2s+2$ for $s$ at least $1$ (so $r\geq 4$), then the number of solutions equals $q^{m-1} + q^{m-s-2}(q-1)$.  When $r$ equals $1$, the number equals $q^{m-1}$.  When $r$ equals $2$, the answer depends on $q$, e.g., if $q=p$ then the answer depends on whether $p$ is congruent to $+1$ or $-1$ modulo $4$.

Comment: What is the role of $r$ vs. $m$?  I assumed that each $X_i$ came from $\mathbb F_q$, but then we seem to be working in $\mathbb F_q^r$, not $\mathbb F_q^m$ (or else just meaninglessly multiplying our answer by $q^{m - r}$).

Comment: @LSpice  I had the same question.  I decided that we are just meaninglessly multiplying the number of solutions by $q^{m-r}$.

Comment: Thanks, @Jason Starr.  Could you please give me a reference where I can get the complete proof?

Comment: I do not know of a reference.  The main ingredient is the Chevalley-Warning theorem.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this is covered in Ireland & Rosen. See also [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/183097/11619).

Answer (score 5):

The answer (already given in comments, with a small misprint/mistake) is:

(a) for even $r=2k+2$, it is $q^{m-1}+(q-1)q^{m-k-2}\eta((-1)^{k+1})$, where $\eta$ is the quadratic character of $\mathbb{F}_q$, $\eta(x)=1$ if $x$ is a square, and $\eta(x)=-1$ if $x$ is not a square.

(b) for odd $r$, it is always $q^{m-1}$.

For the specific reference, see, respectively, Theorems 6.26, 6.27 in [Finite Fields](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/finite-fields/75BDAA74ABAE713196E718392B9E5E72) by Lidl and Niederreiter. The results of those theorems should be applied in the case of dimension $r$, and then multiplied by $q^{m-r}$ (choices for the last $m-r$ coordinates).

Comment: Can you also include the actual answer from the comments in your answer? Comments are not meant to be permanent.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek : done (in fact, there was a little misprint/mistake in the comments in the case of even $r$).